# rspec testing file and fileutils

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file, rspec

I've got a document management system which I programmed in Rails 2.3.8 a while ago and I've been retrofitting some rspec tests to the project before refactoring and making enhancements.

The problem is a lot of my tests require stubbing out most of the File & FileUtils libraries as there is a lot of file interaction within models. Is there a better way to test File & Directory actions without having to touch the filesystem at all?

For instance I stub out mkdir_p:

```
FileUtils.stub!(:mkdir_p)
```

And when I'm moving I use something like this:

```
 FileUtils.should_receive(:mv).with("from path","to path")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [fakefs](https://github.com/defunkt/fakefs). It's perfect for the purpose.

Comment: When I put the following in my Rails 2.3.8 environment.rb file 'config.gem "fakefs", :require => "fakefs/safe"' and run rake it tells me that it 'can not find the plugin named: awesome_nested_set' are these incompatible? does fakefs work with Rails 2.x?

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend to alter File or FileUtils classes, because these changes will affect all your running unit tests. It will be hard to track these changes when you have a lot of different tests and your tests will start affecting each other (which is generally bad testing practice).

I propose to explicitly use a simple manual [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) approach like constructor injection:

```
class UnderTest   
  def initialize file_creator = FileUtils   
    @file_creator = file_creator   
  end

  def use_file_utils    
    @file_creator.mkdir('some_dir')
  end 
end
```

In RSpec test:

```
fake_file_utils = mock "FileUtils"
test = UnderTest.new fake_file_utils 
test.use_file_utils
```

Comment: This makes sense but every time I try this it complains with 'write_attribute_without_dirty'. Do I have to put 'def intialize(*args)' or include 'super' within the initializer?

Comment: @map7, write_attribute_without_dirty is an ActiveRecord method. Can you update the question with the code of the class under test, your test and an error message?

Comment: @map7, think I got it. You are testing class that is a child of another class (in your case it is a child of ActiveRecord class). Then you need to call super (with all required for the base class params) from the overriden constructor in order to initialize base class.